# Empty file in Linux

Tags: linux, automation, touch

I know to create an empty files using touch command in Linux. But how to create a shell script which automatically creates an empty file when the script is executed? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't know whether this is a trick question. But the best answer I can give to you is:

Write a script as follows:

```
touch file.txt
```

Save it as `file-creater.sh` and give it executable permission. Wolla! you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

try too

```
>> <name_file>.txt
```

sample

```
>> sample.txt
```

Comment: I tried below script, but I need script to validate file name is existing in the directory before a empty file gets created,
#!bin/sh                                                                                                         if test ! -f filename
then
echo File does not exit
echo Creating file...
touch filename
else
echo File exit. Do Nothing

Comment: Yes, I undestand so your case best command is Touch, even with very I / O

Answer (score 0):

This commmand should work -

```
cat /dev/null > file_name.log
```